# array_search is not working

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array(0=>array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'emp1'), 1=>array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'emp2'), 2=>array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'emp3'));
echo array_search(2, array_column($arr, 'name', 'id'));
```

The above code is throwing empty value.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_search(2, array_column($arr, 'id', 'name'));
```

is the answer. while you tried

```
array_search(2, array_column($arr, 'name', 'id'));
```

you are passing key as a needle, while array_search searches needle in value,then returns key of matched value.

you can change key position according your requirement in array_column

Answer (score 0):

For multidimensional array you have to use `foreach`

```
  $arr = array(0=>array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'emp1'), 1=>array('id'=>2, 
         'name'=>'emp2'), 2=>array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'emp3'));
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['id'] == "2") {
          echo "id matched";
          echo $key; //if you want array key (1)
          echo $val['id']; // if you want 2's id (2) 
           echo $val['name']; // if you want name (emp2)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE : For PHP >= 5.5.0

I guess you are expecting **emp2** as the output of above code. 
Here,  *array_column($arr, 'name', 'id')* will generate an array like :

```
Array
(
    [1] => emp1
    [2] => emp2
    [3] => emp3
)
```

now, since *array_search()* will search in values, you need your array to look like :

```
Array
(
    [emp1] => 1
    [emp2] => 2
    [emp3] => 3
)
```

So, switch keys in *array_column()*. 
Try,

```
$arr = array(0=>array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'emp1'), 1=>array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'emp2'), 2=>array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'emp3'));
echo array_search(2, array_column($arr, 'id', 'name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. Just rearrange the name after id -

```
$arr = array(0=>array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'emp1'), 1=>array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'emp2'), 2=>array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'emp3'));
echo array_search(2, array_column($arr, 'id', 'name'));
```